# Simple LZW Compression doesnt work

Tags: lua, compression, lzw

I wrote simple class to compress data. Here it is:

```
LZWCompressor = {}
function LZWCompressor.new()
  local self = {}
  self.mDictionary = {}
  self.mDictionaryLen = 0
  -- ...
  self.Encode = function(sInput)
    self:InitDictionary(true)
    local s = ""
    local ch = ""
    local len = string.len(sInput)
    local result = {}   
    local dic = self.mDictionary
    local temp = 0
    for i = 1, len do
        ch = string.sub(sInput, i, i)
        temp = s..ch
        if dic[temp] then
            s = temp
        else
            result[#result + 1] = dic[s]
            self.mDictionaryLen = self.mDictionaryLen + 1   
            dic[temp] = self.mDictionaryLen         
            s = ch
        end
    end
    result[#result + 1] = dic[s]
    return result
  end
  -- ...
  return self
end
```

And i run it by:

```
local compressor = LZWCompression.new()
local encodedData = compressor:Encode("I like LZW, but it doesnt want to compress this text.")


print("Input length:",string.len(originalString))
print("Output length:",#encodedData)


local decodedString = compressor:Decode(encodedData)
print(decodedString)
print(originalString == decodedString)
```

But when i finally run it by lua, it shows that interpreter expected string, not **Table**. That was strange thing, because I pass argument of type string. To test Lua's logs, i wrote at beggining of function:

```
print(typeof(sInput))
```

I got output "Table" and lua's error. So how to fix it? Why lua displays that string (That i have passed) is a table? I use Lua 5.3.

Comment: please show some more effort to solve the problem on your own next time. "why is this code not working" questions tend to get downvoted or deleted on SO. Also I cannot simply run your code to see what is happening as you don't provide a proper [MCVE]. Please read [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is in definition of method Encode(), and most likely Decode() has same problem.
You create Encode() method using dot syntax: `self.Encode = function(sInput)`, 
but then you're calling it with colon syntax: `compressor:Encode(data)`
When you call Encode() with colon syntax, its first implicit argument will be `compressor` itself (table from your error), not the data.
To fix it, declare Encode() method with colon syntax: `function self:Encode(sInput)`, or add 'self' as first argument explicitly `self.Encode = function(self, sInput)`

Answer (score 1):

The code you provided should not run at all.

You define `function LZWCompressor.new()` but call `CLZWCompression.new()`

Inside Encode you call `self:InitDictionary(true)` which has not been defined.

Maybe you did not paste all relevant code here.

The reason for the error you get though is that you call `compressor:Encode(sInput)` which is equivalent to `compressor.Encode(self, sInput)`. (syntactic sugar) As function parameters are not passed by name but by their position `sInput` inside Encode is now `compressor`, not your string.
Your first argument (which happens to be `self`, a table) is then passed to `string.len` which expects a string.
So you acutally call `string.len(compressor)` which of course results in an error.

Please make sure you know how to call and define functions and how to use self properly!

Comment: I have changed CLZWCompression in call to LZWCompression.